# Copy and Redirecting System.err Stream

Tags: java, logging, stream, redirectstandardoutput

I am currently using java.util.logger in my application. It sends its output to System.err. I need it to continue to do this, but I also need to send that output to something else.

Is there a way to copy the System.err stream so that it can send to two different sources?

Answer (score 5):

As always when note people referencing `java.util.logger` I feel inclined to at least recommend looking at another logging library, such as [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) and [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/).

This [blog post](http://blogs.oracle.com/nickstephen/entry/java_redirecting_system_out_and) describes a method which can easily be adapted to support what you're asking for. In short what you need to do is define a PrintStream which can duplicate its output, assign this using:

```
System.setErr(doubleLoggingPrintStream)
```

Comment: Very interesting. I have noticed log4j referenced many times before. Do you suggest one over the other?

Comment: No, it's all preference. We tend to use log4j as most of our dependencies are already based on it. If you use [commons-logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) your application can transparently switch between log4j/slf4j based on which library can be found in your classpath.

Comment: The author of log4j recommends logback: http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html