# Intercepting stderr being generated from another class using Logger?

Tags: java, logging

I have a class generating error output that I'd like to output using Logger. I'm a bit perplexed at how I do this. I have something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ClassA foo = new ClassA();
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClassA.class.getName());
    FileHandler logFile = new FileHandler("LogToFile2.txt");
    logFile.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
    logger.addHandler(logFile);
    logger.info("A message logged to the file");
    foo.bar();
}
```

It outputs "A message logged to the file", but the rest of the INFO stderr I receive from bar() is not captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume bar hass Logger.getLogger calls in it. You should set up the logging application wide in a file called logging.properties.

Right now you are doing it on the Logger instance you retrieved for CobolProgramService.

So when you're calling Logger.getLogger in foo.bar() it will have a standard setup instead.

Check out http://www.crazysquirrel.com/computing/java/logging.jspx for some more advanced information on the topic.

Comment: Sorry, meant to take that out. So I need to have getLogger calls in the other class to?

Comment: Yes, if you write to System.err it will output to stderr. Loggers do not capture the output of stderr.

Comment: Thanks. I know it's not optimal, but is there anyway to catch stdErr whilst preserving console output (i.e don't just redirect)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880401/copy-and-redirecting-system-err-stream/4880428#4880428 answer