# Doubling System.out

Tags: java, outputstream, printstream

I want to write `System.out` messages to another `OutputStream`, but I still want to have the standard output too.

I found an answer on this similar matter [Copy and Redirecting System.err Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880401/copy-and-redirecting-system-err-stream):

> In short what you need to do is define a PrintStream which can duplicate its output, assign this using:

```
System.setErr(doubleLoggingPrintStream)
```

This is what I made so far:

```
public class DoublerPrintStream extends PrintStream {

    private OutputStream forwarder;

    public DoublerPrintStream(OutputStream target, OutputStream forward) {
        super(target, true);
        this.forwarder = forward;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                super.write(b);
                forwarder.write(b);
                forwarder.flush();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        catch (IOException x) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] buf, int off, int len) {
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                super.write(buf, off, len);
                forwarder.write(buf, off, len);
                forwarder.flush();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        catch (IOException x) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int b) {
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                super.write(b);
                forwarder.write(b);
                forwarder.flush();
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
        catch (IOException x) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        super.flush();
        try { forwarder.flush(); } catch (IOException e) { }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        super.close();
        if (forwarder != null) {
            try {
                forwarder.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a draft, but is this a good approach? I'm kind of clueless whether there is a better solution, so I'm looking for confirmation, ideas and suggestions.

Comment: Helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987395/how-to-write-data-to-two-java-io-outputstream-objects-at-once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is an Apache library that does that ([TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html) , thanks @Thilo) but your implementation looks good to me.